# Prove that $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2 - 3) \cong \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Here is the statement of the problem:

> Let $(x^2 - 3)$ be the ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ generated by $x^2 - 3$
>   and let $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}] = \{a + b\sqrt{3} : a,b \in
> > \mathbb{Z}\}$. Prove that $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2 - 3) \cong
> > \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$.

I'm asking this question here because some of these objects are not very familiar to me (and I've having trouble finding similar problems elsewhere). So, I was just wondering if my approach here was correct (and, I suppose, in the "spirit" of the problem—though this is obviously context-dependent).

Here is my approach:

Define a map $\phi: \mathbb{Z}[x] \to \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$ by $\phi(f(x)) = f(\sqrt{3})$. It is clear (right?) that this is a well-defined epimorphism. Moreover, $f \in \ker\phi \iff f(\sqrt{3}) = 0 \iff f \in (x^2 - 3)$; and so $\ker\phi = (x^2 - 3)$. Thus, by the First Isomorphism Theorem,
$$ \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2 - 3) \cong \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}], $$
as desired.

Comment: Seems fine to me. One thing that could possibly use more explanation is the forward direction of $f(\sqrt{3})=0\iff f\in\langle x^2-3\rangle$ (unless this is considered obvious at the level this problem is posed).

Comment: Your claim that $\ker \phi=\langle x^2-3 \rangle$ requires more reasoning, especially knowing the fact that $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is not a PID, you need to justify this carefully.